# Wordpress themes encrypt methods

Tags: wordpress, encryption, themes

I want to create wordpress themes with encrypt link as developer. At another themes, usually I seeing it at the footer.php and function.php. Any body can tell me, what encrypt methods that can i use?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the theme? I'm pretty sure you'd be unable to add to the WordPress.org theme repo with something like that.

Comment: I want share it for free, but people who used my themes cant remove my footer link as designer. So I need encrypt it, than people who used my themes cant remove my author link. Can you give me solutions?

Comment: Typically you see base_64 and eval (PHP) being used to obscure the code. There's no way to stop users removing your link, you can only make it more difficult for them to do so.

Comment: yes thanks, I think base_64 will be solutions for my problem. Thanks for your suggestions, I really appreciate it :)